# Apostrophe in JQuery Autocomplete Call

Tags: c#, asp.net, jquery-ui, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

The code below works when searching for any name that does not contain an apostrophe.  When you attempt to find someone with an apostrophe in their name it fails (returns error).  How can I allow to find people with apostrophes?

```
function autoComplete() {
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".AutoCompleteClass").autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "/Service/NomineeWebService.asmx/GetMatchingActiveDirectoryUsers",
                data: "{ 'SearchCharacters': '" + request.term + "' }",
                dataType: "json",
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataFilter: function (data) { return data; },
                success: function (data) {
                    response($.map(data.d, function (item) {
                        return {
                            id: item.NomineeUserName,
                            value: item.NomineeLastNameFirstName + " - " + item.NomineeDomainAndUserName,
                            data: item
                        }
                    }))
                },
                error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert(textStatus);
                }
            });
        },            
        delay: 150,
        minLength: 3,            
        select: function (event, ui) {
            $('.SelectedUserNameWrapper input[type=hidden]').val(ui.item.id);
        }       
    });
});
$('#AutoCompleteTextBox').keypress(function (event) {
    if (event.which == '13') {
        alert('test');
        $('#AutoCompleteButton').click();
    }
```

Comment: What is the error, what is the output of the ajax-call, is the error in javascript or on the server side?

Comment: The alert box is coming up, but just says "error".  It doesnt return a message.  The database that it is querying has names with apostrophes in them, so I dont suspect anything happening on the server side.

Comment: It sounds likely that the single-quotes (in your input) need to be escaped before being used to query the database.

Comment: This does not work:  data: "{ 'SearchCharacters': '" + request.term.replace("'", "\'") + "' }",

Comment: What database system?  Usually (I think) to escape single quotes you want to use another single quote ('').  If that doesn't do it, I'll delete my answer - I just know I've run into that before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kind of quirky, but I ended up doing the replace like this:  request.term.replace("'", "%27")

Then on my web service, I intercept and replace back to using the apostrophe:
SearchCharacters = SearchCharacters.Replace("%27", "'");
and pass that to my database call.

This works.  It is something in the autocomplete plugin or jquery stuff.  Since this works, I will use it and move on.

Thanks for all the suggestions.  By the way, none of the escaping worked for me...

Thanks again...

Comment: Thanks this worked for me also... I tried some of the solutions above and they didn't work... but this one did the trick! `request.term.replace("'", "%27")`

Answer (score 7):

I found resolution to this issue, we should replace all "'" with escape characters. Code looks like below

```
    function autoComplete() {
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".AutoCompleteClass").autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
request.term = request.term.replace(/'/gi,"\\'"); // replace globally
```

Answer (score 4):

It sounds likely that the single-quotes (in your input) need to be escaped before being used to query the database.  Try replacing the "data" portion of your AJAX call with something like this:

```
data: "{ 'SearchCharacters': '" + request.term.replace("'", "''")  + "' }",
```

My jQuery syntax might be a little off, but hopefully that conveys what I'm trying to say.

If that does it, you might run into this problem with other special characters too down the road.

**Note:** An extra single quote is the "escape character" for single quotes in mySQL and SQL Server.  You didn't mention what RDBMS you're using, so it might be different for you.

**Obligatory:** You probably know this, but hopefully you're not concatenating that "request.term" value with an SQL query on the server-side.  That would make you vulnerable to [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) =)

Comment: @MikeRichards Good catch!  Copy / Paste fail on my part.